# Javascript não reconhece Json

Tags: javascript

tenho a seguinte ideia que o moderador Sergio enviou

```
var obj = [JSON]

var mydiv = document.getElementById("tabLista");
mydiv.innerHTML = "";
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
mydiv.appendChild(ul);

var escolhidas = [];
obj.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj = obj.List;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add(chave);
    div.textContent = obj[chave];
    li.appendChild(div);
  });
  var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.closest('li').classList.toggle('selecionado', this.checked);
    if (this.checked) escolhidas.push(obj);
    else escolhidas = escolhidas.filter(function(el) {
      return el != obj;
    });
    console.log(escolhidas);
  });
  li.appendChild(checkbox);
});
```

Só que na hora de inserir o json que o meu servidor responde o script não reconhece as chaves, somente imprime

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Json que o meu servidor responde

```
{
    "api": "api",
    "List": [{
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Marcelo"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Pedro"
    }, {
        "tipo": "1",
        "data": "10/10/2017",
        "Hora": "11:38",
        "Size": "0",
        "Nome": "Lucas"
    }],
    "arq": "1",
    "paste": "2"
}
```

Json Da ideia original

```
var obj = [{
    nome: 'a',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
  {
    nome: 'b',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
  {
    nome: 'c',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
  {
    nome: 'd',
    data: '13/09/2017'
  },
]
```

Obigado :)

Comment: Em qual trecho isso é impresso? Porque ele está imprimindo um objeto, talvez tenha que imprimir uma string ou trabalhar o objeto.

Comment: E se você trocar console.log(escolhidas) por console.log(JSON.stringify(escolhidas, null, 2)); o que exibe?

Comment: Ele está sendo impresso na div tabLista, com o json do Sergio funciona normalmente, mas com o meu não, trocando o console.log volta "Null"

Comment: @PlanetWar estás com problemas a enviar para o servidor ou a receber do servidor?

Comment: Receber o json e imprimir na li

Comment: Ok, qual é o código JavaScript que vai buscar o JSON?

Comment: Outra coisa, estás a dar o nome de `JSON` à variável? `JSON` (com letra grande) é uma palavra reservada em JavaScript, deves usar outra.

Comment: Não, só coloquei JSON ali para mostrar onde o meu json vai, mas estou colocando ali a resposta do JSON.parse(req.responseText);

Comment: E depois estás a usar `var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);` ou `var obj = [JSON.parse(req.responseText)];`?

Comment: Estou usando var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

Comment: Ok, então muda para `var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText).List;` e depois tira o `obj = obj.List;` dentro do `.forEach`. O problema é que estás a passar o objeto e não uma array. Ou então deixa como está mas passa uma array, no caso de teres vários desses JSONs.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado por esclarecer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JSON que recebes do servidor é um objeto:

```
{
    "api": "api",
    "List": [{
```

e o `.forEach` trabalha sobre arrays. Assim tens de passar o `.List` diretamente pois o `.List` é uma array.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

var mydiv = document.getElementById("tabLista");
mydiv.innerHTML = "";
var ul = document.createElement("ul");
mydiv.appendChild(ul);

var escolhidas = [];
obj.forEach(function(obj) {
  // obj = obj.List; // <--- tira isto. Isto era util caso `obj` fosse uma array.
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  ul.appendChild(li);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(chave) {
  // etc...
```